# how to update the product description in a specified category?

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.6

I want to set all the product with the same description  with a specified category id using the following sql code but it doesn't update the product with the same description when under the same category.

```
update catalog_product_entity_text
  set value = "the product's name test hah test."
  where attribute_id = 66 and
        entity_id (select product_id from catalog_category_product
                    where category_id = 40);
```

thank you.

Comment: can you say a little about the table(s) involved - e.g. name of columns and a couple of rows.

Comment: don't you get an error for this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "entity_id IN ..." like so:

```
update catalog_product_entity_text
  set value = "the product's name test hah test."
  where attribute_id = 66 and
        entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product
                    where category_id = 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write `IN` between entity_id and the select query.

I don't know which version you are using but for me the attribute_id of the short_description is 65 and it is 64 for the description.

Comment: i add in but it still can't work, the version is Magento ver. 1.6.2.0 how do you know  the attribute_id of the short_description is 65

Comment: Check the database table eav_attribute, search with the attribute_code